# Can't change class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React. I want to change an element's class.

```
var NGform = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var classes = 'mmm';
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="{classes}">
                    <label className="form-label">Logo</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    React.createElement(NGform, null),
    document.getElementById('new')
);
```

But the class name doesn't change:

```
<div class="{classes}" data-reactid=".0.0">
```

Why not?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4Uwb/5/)

Comment: you should remove quotes: `className={classes}`

Comment: you are welcome. With quotes it is just a string, without quotes it is javascript context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
div className="{classes}"
```

to

```
div className={classes}
```

see if that works for you, this way it wont take {classes} as a string but as the data bind